# Time homogeneous Markov chain with random times

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A continuous time homogeneous Markov chain $X_t$ over a finite state space $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$ satisfies the property

$$P(X(s+t) = j \mid X(t) = i) = P(X(s) = j \mid X(0) = i).$$

If $S$ and $T$ are random times is it then true that

$$P(X(S+T) = j \mid X(T) = i) = P(X(S) = j \mid X(0) = i).$$

Edit: See the comments for a nice counterexample in the case $S$ deterministic and $T$ random but not stopping time (for discrete time Markov chains). Now what happens if we restrict $T$ to be a stopping time?

Comment: I guess this question can be restated as: Does ever continuous time homogenous Markov chain $X_t$ with finite state space satisfy the strong markov property: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property.

Comment: I was also thinking about the strong Markov property, but I don't see the connection. In fact the above question is only concerned with the homogeneity property and not (directly) with the history of the process. Note also that S and T need not be stopping times and in general not independent. (In my application I think both are stopping times but for sure not independent.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I did read them as stopping times, not random times.

Comment: I think it will hold if stopping times $S$ and $T$ are independent, but not in general.

Comment: Counterexample: X a transient random walk on the positive integers, S=1, T=last visit to 2. Then, for i=2, j=3, the LHS is 1 and the RHS p(2,3).

Comment: For a counterexample in continuous time where $S$ and $T$ are stopping times, I would compute carefully both sides when $X$ is the Markov chain on $\{0,1\}$ starting from $X_0=0$, with equal transition rates from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $0$, $T=1$ and $S=\inf\{t\gt0\mid X_t=1\}$. Then $P(X_S=1\mid X_0=0)=1$ but $P(X_{S+1}=0\mid X_1=0)\geqslant P(X_{S+1}=0,S\gt1\mid X_1=0)=p_1(1,0)>0$ hence $P(X_{S+1}=1\mid X_1=0)\ne P(X_S=1\mid X_0=0)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample, thank you. I only see that $P(X_{S+1} = 0 \mid X_1 = 0) > 0$ (which is enough for the contradiction). But I don't see why $P(X_{S+1} = 0, S > 1 \mid X_1 = 0) = p_1(1,0)$, i.e. the probability to find the Markov chain in state $0$ at time $t = 1$ when starting in state $1$ at time $t = 0$.

Comment: Strong Markov property at time $S$ since $X_S=1$ almost surely.